# При нажатии на кнопку взять её id с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" id="123" value="Кнопка" name="qwe">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sub').click(function() {
    var clickId = $(this).attr('id');
  });
});
```

Элемент админки где в `id` хранится `id` редактируемой строки в базе.

Comment: Вы уже задавали такой вопрос и вам на него отвечали. В чем проблема?

Comment: Там не использовали ajax

Comment: Ну и где обработчик нажатия на кнопку? Или его тоже __нам__ надо написать?

Comment: Немного отредактировал код

Comment: Если вам нужен ajax - то обработчик нажатия на кнопку должен быть на клиенте на джаваскрипте, есть у вас такой?

Comment: Нет нету, а так нельзя сделать как у меня ?

Comment: Может вам пора почитать что такое ajax?

Comment: @u_mulder я добавил обработчик нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Ну и в обработчике вы получаете ИД кнопки. В чем опять проблема?

Comment: Я не могу использовать полученный id в php.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, чтобы стандартный `submit` не отрабатывался при нажатии на кнопку нужно его отменить, ну и в итоге получается как-то так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.sub').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // отменяем стандартную обработку кнопки submit
        var clickId = $(this).attr('id');

        // вот тут используете отправку id $.ajax или $.get или $.post
   });
});
```